# convert text as uppercase

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, mudblazor

i want to take uppercase only even if i am entering lowercase it should convert in uppercase in text field in mudblazor.

```
 <MudTextField For="@(() => AddEditItemModel.HSNSAC)"
               @bind-Value="AddEditItemModel.HSNSAC"
               Label="@_localizer["SAC"]"
               MaxLength="3">
 </MudTextField>
```

i tried to call through @onclick method and tried to handle with method, but the issue is that method is getting called.

```
<MudTextField For="@(() => AddEditItemModel.HSNSAC)"
              @bind-Value="AddEditItemModel.HSNSAC"
              Label="@_localizer["SAC"]" MaxLength="3" 
              @oninput="ConvertToUppercase"
</MudTextField>
```

Comment: for me its not working , is there any other to take input as uppercase only ?

Comment: You should be able to achieve this by doing something like: `<MudTextField ValueChanged="(value) => AddEditItemModel.HSNSAC = value.ToUpper()"></MudTextField>`

Comment: its giving error while using  value.ToUpper() in my code i.e.  <MudTextField ValueChanged="(value) => AddEditItemModel.HSNSAC = value.ToUpper()" Label="@_localizer["SAC"]" MaxLength="3"></MudTextField>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Value` and `ValueChanged` instead of `@bind-Value` if you want to add custom logic for when the value changes.

The changed value will be passed to the handler method that you assign to `ValueChanged`.

Since `Value` is a property of type `T` you need to define the it in the component e.g. `T="string"`. [docs](https://mudblazor.com/api/textfield#properties)

Another tip: You can also set `Immediate="true"` if you want it to change to uppercase on each input.

```html
 <MudTextField For="@(() => AddEditItemModel.HSNSAC)"
               Value="AddEditItemModel.HSNSAC"
               ValueChanged="HandleValueChanged"
               MaxLength="3" 
               T="string" 
               Label="@_localizer["SAC"]"
               Immediate="true">
 </MudTextField>
 @code{
    void HandleValueChanged(string newValue)
    {
        AddEditItemModel.HSNSAC = newValue.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QkGxuNFGyVtBSmGP)

Alternatively, you can use the `Text` and `TextChanged` where the type used for those are `string` so `T` does not need to be declared.

```html
 <MudTextField For="@(() => AddEditItemModel.HSNSAC)"
               Text="@AddEditItemModel.HSNSAC"
               TextChanged="HandleTextChanged"
               MaxLength="3" 
               Label="@_localizer["SAC"]"
               Immediate="true">
 </MudTextField>
 @code{
    void HandleTextChanged(string newValue)
    {
        AddEditItemModel.HSNSAC = newValue.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert text to uppercase as the user types you need to do the following:

```
<MudTextField Label="SAC"  
              T="string"
              Value="addEditItemModel.HSNSAC" 
              ValueChanged="(value) => addEditItemModel.HSNSAC = value.ToUpper()"
              Immediate="true"
              For="@(() => addEditItemModel.HSNSAC)" 
              MaxLength="3" />

<p>@addEditItemModel.HSNSAC</p>

@code {
 private AddEditItemModel addEditItemModel = new AddEditItemModel(); 

 public class AddEditItemModel
    {
       public string HSNSAC { get; set; } 
    }  
}
```